# Why is MVC JsonResult controller method returning HTML markup in browser

Tags: json, model-view-controller, jsonresult

So I have a controller called **'HistoryController'** which has a 'JsonResult' action which returns json data.

[image]

There is no associated View or Model with this method.

When I enter the url .../HistoryController/GetData, I get strange behaviour.

Instead of getting the json data (or maybe even an error message), I get the entire master page markup back in the browser. Why is this?

All I want is for some json data to show in browser but what I get is this:

[image]

Comment: can you paste the controller code with request mappings

Comment: What do you mean by 'request mappings'? I am using ASP.NET MVC by the way.